# play rtsp video in Media Player in iphone

Tags: iphone, media-player, rtsp

I have source code for RtspFrames from Github. I have downloaded source code from this link :

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RtspFrames-test

I want to play rtsp video in custom Media player in iphone How to implement in this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at some of the other projects on our github repository, ffplayer-tests or rtspplay might be more appropriate for what you want.

Comment: Hi Michelle, Ya you are right i have run the code for rtspplay on device But how can i play video in MPMoviePlayer in iphone because it is running in UIImageview so pls let me know how can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am shocking there is no answer for this post. It means there is no anyone who knows RTSP play in iphone. In the other hand there are various apps available in itunes store like http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/oplayer-lite-best-free-video/id385907472?mt=8